# fail to deploy with dropbox on heroku

Tags: heroku, dropbox

I'm new with heroku and i'm trying to deploy my simple php project using dropbox i already succeeded deploying 2 php project and 1 play v2 app , but this time i always get this error.

[image]

Comment: This may be something Heroku support would be better suited to help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Old reply, but I managed to solved this by deleting both (deleting only one didn't help):

- heroku from dropbox page under applications tab.
- dropbox from heroku page under account -> applications.